# XCTest CLLocationManager's delegate methods don't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, xctest

I'm writing test cases for my iBeaconManager. Inside my iBeaconManager contains a CLLocationManager instance and its delegate is set to iBeaconManager. I passed an array of CLCircularRegions to my iBeaconManager called my location manager's [startMonitoringForRegion:] method for each region. My location manager's [didStartMonitoringForRegion:] doesn't get called for some reason. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your test calls `startMonitoringForRegion:`. Depending on your setup, this may or may not trigger a callback. But even if it does, it's asynchronous and will take time. The test finishes and disappears before this can happen.

Try one of these approaches, depending on your goals:

1. **End-to-end test:** Have your test re-synchronize the asynchronous operation. If you're using straight XCTest, make an XCTestExpectation that is fulfilled. Other add-on test libraries can make synchronizing easier. (I prefer OCHamcrest's `assertWithTimeout`.)
2. **Unit test:** Don't use an actual CLLocationManager. Instead, inject a fake. Your test can then directly call `didStartMonitoringForRegion:` *as if* it had been invoked by CLLocationManager. This is the normal way to test callbacks from any framework.

Advantages of the unit test approach include speed, reliability, and you can run on Simulator (so it can be part of your continuous integration). Also, you can simulate any number of conditions without having to create those conditions. For example, it's easy to call back with errors or other edge cases.